# Coordinating conjunction but verb comes first?

Tags: meaning, verb, word-order, adverb

> Paul war krank und konnte daher nicht kommen.

Warum kommt 'konnte' zuerst im zweiten Satz? Ich verstehe nicht, weil 'konnte' ein Verb ist. Sollte das Verb nicht an zweiter Stelle stehen? .

Könnte jemand mir hier die Grammatik in Ruhe erklären?

Danke schön.

Comment: "*konnte*" ist keine Konjunktion, sondern ein Verb. (Präteritum 3. Person Singular von "*können*") Meinst Du vielleicht "*und*" als Konjunktion? Hier ist "*und*" eine Aufzählung. Was meinst Du mit "*in der zweiten Klasse*"? Ist das eine fehlerhafte Übersetzung von englisch "*clause*"?

Comment: Ja, du bist richtig. Sorry, mein deutschschreiben ist noch schlecht. Ich habe Ihren Vorschlag jetzt aufgenommen und die Frage bearbeitet. @Bodo

Comment: It helps to keep the question title and the question in the same language. This is how people know whether to answer in English or German.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Konjunktion ist *und*, sie verbindet in diesem Fall zwei Hauptsätze, die man auch folgendermaßen schreiben könnte:

> (1) Paul war krank. Er konnte daher nicht kommen.

(In beiden Fällen steht das Verb, im zweiten Satz *kommen* an zweiter Stelle, wie immer in deutschen Hauptsätzen)

Bei der Verbindung mit *und* kann man im zweiten Satz das Subjekt weglassen.

> (2) Paul war krank, und er konnte daher nicht kommen.
>
> (3) Paul war krank und konnte daher nicht kommen.

Wenn es ein neues Subjekt ist, geht das natürlich nicht:

> Paul war krank, und seine Schwester konnte daher nicht kommen.

Hier kann man *seine Schwester* nicht weglassen.

Die beiden Formen mit Subjekt (1, 2) klingen holpriger (vor allem 1) als die Form aus Deinem Beispiel (3). Richtig sind alle drei.